# Why android create a lot of ModerAsyncTask/AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I noticed that, when I go to the activity, android will create new ModernAsyncTask or AsyncTask instances, but no more than 5. I am searched in google but not find helpful information about this. It's normal or no?

ModernAsyncTask created on acrivity with Loader, I just go from activity A to activity B, pushed back to A, again go to the activity B, many times

for AsyncTask I had to press button on activity B that show the dialog.

here is the screen

[image]

Comment: You aren't using any AsyncTask in your code?

Comment: @SergeyGlotov
нет, именно AsyncTask не использую, использую Loader

Comment: Each Loader creates AsyncTask. 5 can be default size of pool of AsyncTasks on your device. Is there something wrong? I don't understand the question really. // Каждый Loader создаёт AsyncTask внутри. А 5 – размер пула AsyncTask'ов на твоём устройстве, скорее всего. Я не понимаю, в чём именно проблема.

Comment: @SergeyGlotov
Проблема в том, что потоки эти не разрушаются, они висят дальше и тормозят приложения, Я думал, что причина множественного добавления ModerAsycnTask/AsyncTask это неправильная реализация работы Loader'a или БД. Если это нормальное поведение, то проблемы нет.
//
The problem is that these flows are not destroyed, they hang on and brake application, I thought, that the reason for adding multiple ModerAsycnTask / AsyncTask it's incorrect implementation of Loader or opened database connection. If this is normal behavior, i have no problem.